# How to get row value inside of TableColumn.setCellFactory() callback

Tags: javafx

I have a table column `TableColumn<Data,Object>` that I need to display in a table. The `TableCell<Data,Object>` depends not only on the `Object` type (which can be different for each table row), but also on the `Data` value of the corresponding table row. .

My idea was to create an abstract class `AbstractTableCell` implementing common features and individual subclasses for each type of field editor. The callback `setCellFactoryCallback` would then select the appropriate type. Something like :

```
Callback<TableColumn<Data, Object>, TableCell<Data, Object>> callback = 
        new Callback<TableColumn<Data, Object>, TableCell<Data, Object>>() {
            
    @Override
    public TableCell<Data, Object> call(TableColumn<Data, Object> param) {
    
         Object value = param.get???;    // how to get it here
         Data   data  = param.get???;    // how to get it here

         if (value instanceof XY && data.someField=1) {
               return new FieldXY1TableCell<Data,YX>(data, value);
         } else if { value instanceof XY && data.someField=2
               return new FieldXY2TableCell<Data,XY>(data, value);
         } else if {
               // etc.
         } else {
               return TextFieldTableCell.<Data>forTableColumn();
         }
    };
```

My question is how to get the value of the cell and the value of the table row in the callback, so I can then make a decision which `TableCell` renderer will be responsible for the presentation. Or is it too early for such a decision and the specific cell data is known only later, for example in `TableCell.updateItem()`method?

Answer (score 3):

> Or is it too early for such a decision and the specific cell data is known only later, for example in `TableCell.updateItem()` method?

This is correct. The cell you return will be used later to display a value (specifically a value determined by applying the column's cell value factory to an element of the table's items list). At that time, `updateItem(...)` will be called with the item to be displayed (or `null` if there is no item in that cell).

Furthermore, the cell may (and likely will) be reused at a later point to display a different value (by applying the cell value factory to a different element of the table's items list). At this point, `updateItem(...)` will be called again with the new value to display. This reuse can potentially happen quite often, e.g. when the user is scrolling.

Consequently, your cell factory must return a cell capable of displaying any value possible in that column. The logic determining how to display the value has to be implemented in the `updateItem(...)` method for the cell.

Comment: After converting the logic to the `updateItem(...)` method, everything works as expected. I think that the fact that `updateItem(...)` cannot store any status is very important. In my first solution, when I converted the logic to `updateItem(...)`, I stored instances of the `Control` user interface objects as `TableCell` fields, and it was still not clear to me why there were some unexplained type mismatches from time to time.